# What is the command in selenium python that says wait for all elements on page to load?

Tags: selenium

Is there a code in selenium python that says wait for all elements on page to load?. If so what is the code?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`webdriver` will wait for a page to load by default.

It does not wait for loading inside frames or for `ajax` requests. It means when you use `.get('url')`, your browser will wait until the page is completely loaded and then go to the next command in the code. But when you are posting an `ajax` request, `webdriver` does not wait and it's your responsibility to wait an appropriate amount of time for the page or a part of page to load; so there is a module named `expected_conditions`.

Comment: If I put WebDriverWait(driver, 0) and  WebDriverWait(driver, 20) what would the differences be here?. I read somewhere its seconds but is that miliseconds?

Comment: This is an explicit wait. Explicit waits are confined to a particular web element is applied on the certain element with defined expected condition and time. This wait is only applied to the specified element. This wait can also throw exception when element is not found.

Comment: it falls back to seconds, but that's deprecated methinks... now you'd set duration.ofSeconds/Milliseconds/etc...  so the polling loop will ignore certain exceptions (such as no such element) until the timeout period is reached. https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html

Comment: By default there's a 1/2 second sleep in there... so polling interval is 1/2 second... any timeout period under .5 seconds is the same as without the webdriverwait.  (See FluentWait for full details on the loop as WebDriverWait is just a pre-configured FluentWait...)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following ex with selecting specific element in the page to wait:

```
try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'element_id'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
except TimeoutException:
    print "Timed out waitingenter code here"
```