# Python Webdriver wait until url loaded with no timeout

Tags: python, selenium

How do I set timeout not 30 seconds but until the page is loaded, or any other solution for page wait to loaded fully ?

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.url_to_be(link))
```

Comment: Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72034335/11863448 will help you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.